# Check number of Dates in Date Range that are sequential in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create a function that returns the number of Dates in a Date Range that are sequential, starting on a specific date.

**Example:**

StartDate: 9/1/2022

Date Range: 9/1/2022, 9/2/2022, 9/3/2022, 9/4/2022, 9/7/2022

In this scenario the function I'm looking for would return 4.

Assume dates could be unordered and they can roll over into the next month, so with StartDate 9/29/2022:

9/29/2022, 9/30/2022, 10/1/2022, 10/4/2022 would return 3.

I know I can loop through the dates starting at the specific date and check the number of consecutive days, but I'm wondering if there's a clean way to do it with Linq.

Comment: LINQ will almost definitely _not_ be "cleaner" in this case. Just sort the collection, and then use a loop to iterate the result until you find a gap. That'll probably be the simplest way.

Comment: Are you always looking for the number of consecutive days from the first day or the longest sequence anywhere in the range? I agree that a loop will be your best bet.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm looking for the number of consecutive days from the StartDate. There is no guarantee that the Date Range will begin at the StartDate, but if it does then look for number of consecutive days after that.

Comment: Yup, a loop is your best bet. Someone may come up with some complex LINQ expression, but a loop (with simple comments) will be much easier to read and to maintain. It won't be cheap O(N log(N)) for the sort plus another (inconsequential) O(N) for the loop, but it's _clean_. Make sure you strip away any _Time_ information using `DateTime.Date`; it will make evaluating _sequential_ much simpler

Comment: @Flydog57 how do I strip away the time information using linq on the ordered list?

Comment: `var sorted = datesList.Select(d => d.Date).OrderBy(d => d);` (warning, coding on my phone). No need to call `ToList`, the `sorted` variable is enumerable and things will get materialized as you `foreach` through the result

Comment: "Range" is the wrong word here. What you have is a list or a set of dates, not a range of dates. A [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range) is something that is defined with a `Start` and an `End`. These two are its only properties.

Comment: What is the correct result for this set of dates: 2022-1-15, 2022-1-16, 2022-2-15, 2022-2-16? The set is composed by two pairs of consecutive dates. Is the result 2 or 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a loop would probably be the cleanest way to go. I would use something like the following:

```
List<DateTime> GetConsecutiveDates(IEnumerable<DateTime> range, DateTime startDate)
{
    var orderedRange = range.OrderBy(d => d).ToList();
    int startDateIndex = orderedRange.IndexOf(startDate);
    if (startDateIndex == -1) return null;

    var consecutiveDates = new List<DateTime> { orderedRange[startDateIndex] };
    for (int i = startDateIndex + 1; i < orderedRange.Count; i++)
    {
        if (orderedRange[i] != orderedRange[i - 1].AddDays(1)) break;

        consecutiveDates.Add(orderedRange[i]);
    }
    return consecutiveDates;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the cleanest solution I can come up with...

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2022, 9, 1);

var days = new List<DateTime>()
{
    new(2022, 8, 28),
    new(2022, 9, 1),
    new(2022, 9, 2),
    new(2022, 9, 3),
    new(2022, 9, 4),
    new(2022, 9, 7)
};

var consecutiveDays = GetConsecutiveDays(startDate, days);

foreach (var day in consecutiveDays)
{
    Console.WriteLine(day);
}

Console.ReadKey();

static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetConsecutiveDays(DateTime startDate, IEnumerable<DateTime> days)
{
    var wantedDate = startDate;
    foreach (var day in days.Where(d => d >= startDate).OrderBy(d => d))
    {
        if (day == wantedDate)
        {
            yield return day;
            wantedDate = wantedDate.AddDays(1);
        }
        else
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:
01.09.2022 0:00:00
02.09.2022 0:00:00
03.09.2022 0:00:00
04.09.2022 0:00:00

If you wanted the count, you can call .Count() on the result or just modify the method... Should be easy.

Answer (score 3):

To count the number of consecutive dates in a given date range.

1. first parse the dates from a string and order them in ascending order.
2. Then, use the `TakeWhile` method to take a sequence of consecutive dates from the start of the list.
3. Finally, count the number of elements in the returned sequence and display the result.

```cs
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dateRange = "9/29/2022, 9/30/2022, 10/1/2022, 10/4/2022";
        var dates = dateRange
            .Split(", ")
            .Select(dateStr =>
            {
                var dateData = dateStr.Split("/");
                var month = int.Parse(dateData[0]);
                var day = int.Parse(dateData[1]);
                var year = int.Parse(dateData[2]);
                return new DateTime(year, month, day);
            })
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .ToList();

        var consecutiveDatesCounter = dates
            .TakeWhile((date, i) => i == 0 || dates[i - 1].AddDays(1) == date)
            .Count();

        Console.WriteLine(consecutiveDatesCounter);
    }
}
```

Output: `3`

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tYdWvz

Comment: I'm not trying to generate dates, I have a date range and I'm trying to check how many days starting at the StartDate are consecutive dates.

Comment: @Deivinho Ok noted. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: @Deivinho I have updated my answer to count for the number of consecutive days in a date range. Please do check it out and let me know.

Comment: @Deivinho I have updated the code to prevent counting other consecutive dates within the range. e.g. 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9 should not continue counting after 5 for 7, 8, 9 consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach using a loop. (I agree with the others that said a loop would be cleaner than using Linq for this task.)

```
public static int NumConsecutiveDays(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
    var previous = DateTime.MinValue;
    var oneDay   = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    int result   = 0;

    foreach (var current in dates.OrderBy(d => d))
    {
        if (current.Date - previous.Date == oneDay)
            ++result;

        previous = current;
    }

    return result > 0 ? result + 1 : 0;  // Need to add 1 to result if it is not zero.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var dates = new List<DateTime>() {new DateTime(2014,1,1), new DateTime(2014, 1, 2), new DateTime(2014, 1, 3) , new DateTime(2014, 1, 5), new DateTime(2014, 1, 6), new DateTime(2014, 1, 8) };

  var startDate = new DateTime(2014,1,2);

  var EarliestContiguousDates = dates.Where(x => x>=startDate).OrderBy(x => x)
    .Select((x, i) => new { date = x, RangeStartDate = x.AddDays(-i) })
    .TakeWhile(x => x.RangeStartDate == dates.Where(y => y >= startDate).Min()).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're either going to sort the dates and find sequential ones, or leave it unsorted and repeatedly iterate over the set looking for a match.

Here's the latter dumb approach, leaving it unsorted and using repeated calls to 'IndexOf`:

```
  public static int CountConsecutiveDays(DateTime startingFrom, List<DateTime> data) 
  {
    int count = 0;
    int index = data.IndexOf(startingFrom);
    while(index != -1) {
      count++;
      startingFrom = startingFrom.AddDays(1);
      index = data.IndexOf(startingFrom);
    }
    return count;
  }
```